# Google analytics per page

Tags: google-analytics

I'd like to post alot of Google Analytics info about a page(node) on the page itself(visits, new visits, bounce rate, maybe even time series). What's the best module for this?

In particular, the info is for users that create their own pages and need to see analytics for their pages.

Any hints?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Drupal SEO may be what you are looking for.  http://drupal.org/project/seotools

From its project page:

> The Drupal SEO Tools module seamlessly integrates a sophisticated all-in-one suite of search engine reporting, analysis and optimization tools into your website. It provides a dashboard that integrates analytics reports with links to webmaster tools and vital Drupal SEO modules.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports also provides this functionality.  The 3.x branch includes Views support that allows you to create custom reports.

Some details from the project page:

> Google Analytics Reports module provides graphical reporting of your site's tracking data. Graphical reports include small path-based report in blocks, and a full path-based report.